# System Boots to intrafms, no access to GUI

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu a month ago and afterwards I mistakenly did a force hardisk wipe and stopped it in the middle. From then it booted to a grub menu and I tried to recover my system, but to no avail. So I considered going in for other linux distros but everytime I installed them they booted to busybox intrafms and I never got to see their UI. Please, could anyone help, this is my main machine and no system ever boots to the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

**I assume you have already destroyed ALL files on your hard drive, (or all  of your hard drives if you have several), and you are not trying to  get ANY of your files back at this point.**

**For example, the following instructions will destroy any Windows recovery partition**.

---

I would try re-installing the same version of Ubuntu from a Ubuntu Live USB / dvd.  But before you run the install, you can try and reset your drive to a more pristine state.   Here are some Terminal commands.

I wrote these commands assuming `/dev/sda` is your main hard drive, and you have no other hard drives (apart from the Live USB you boot from).  You may need to adjust them, particularly if you use an NVME drive instead of a SATA drive.  A good way to look at your drives is the Terminal command  `lsblk`.

1. `sudo wipefs --all /dev/sda*`
2. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=10`
3. reboot

The first command will look for filesystems on any existing partitions, and very surgically destroy them.  It will also surgically destroy the partition table.  This includes formats which store some data at the *end*, which includes GPT partition tables.

The second command will replace the first 10 megabytes of your drive with zeros.  This should more crudley erase the partition table (in the first 1MB), the identifying header of a filesystem that *was* in the first partition (in the next 1MB), and any associated boot blocks.  And maybe the second partition, if the first partition was very small.